# In Flink(on yarn, per-Job mode), Why is Maximum heap size in taskmanager.log not equal to the value of 'xmx'?

Tags: memory, jvm, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, flink-streaming

I submit a Flink job to Yarn, Flink version is 1.9, and the submission mod is per-Job, but i find the Maximum heap size in taskmanager.log is always lower than the value of 'xmx' in Java Options, details can be seen in the picture, i want to know what is the reason?
[taskmanager.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbX1.png)

Comment: One possible guess is that you have different definitions of megabyte involved. For example 1024 kilobytes versus 1000 kilobytes

Comment: One of the [survivor spaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/generations.html) is always empty and not included in the calculation of `Runtime.maxMemory`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005220/why-does-my-garbage-collection-log-show-3-8gb-as-the-max-available-heap-size-whi).

Comment: First, i checked the definitions of megabyte involed, both of them use 1024 kilobytes; And secondly, the value is sitll not equal to the value of Runtime.maxMemory after i substract the space of one survivor space from -xmx.